# Инициализация свойств класса PHP

Tags: php

Вероятно кому-то мой вопрос покажется глупым, и наверное он такой и есть, но извините и не судите строго, такая на первый взгляд очевидная штука как присвоение значения свойству класса вызвала у меня непонимание происходящего, подскажите, как присвоить значение одного свойства класса другому свойству этого же класса, в данном случае компилятор ругается на точку с запятой и я не понимаю почему. Подскажите как это делается правильно?

```
class Some_class{

  public $var1 = 'some_text';

  public $var2 = $this->var1.'some_text';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как ответил @etki, на момент объявления класса еще нет $this, поэтому $this->var1 еще не существует, и использовать его для инициализации другого свойства еще нельзя.

Однако, если очень хочется, то можно объявить какие-то значения константами, и использовать их при инициализации переменных

```
class Some_class{
    const MYTEXT = 'some_text';

    public $var1 = self::MYTEXT;
    public $var2 = self::MYTEXT.'some_text';
}

$sc = new Some_class();
var_dump($sc);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP поддерживает подобную обработку только в конструкторе:

```
class Example {
    private $alpha = 1;
    private $beta;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beta = $this->alpha + 1;
    }
}
```

В данном случае вы только описываете класс, поэтому не можете использовать выражения для указания значений - в этом контексте попросту нету $this, т.к. вы задаете значения по умолчанию еще до того, как дойдет до создания объектов.